# How to use sum for lists of custom types?

Tags: scala

Refer to below snippet:

```
class Foo(val b:BigDecimal) {
  def +(f:Foo) = new Foo(b+f.b) 
}
val l = List(new Foo(1), new Foo(2))

l.sum // gives error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Foo]
```

What is the easiest way to get this to work? I know I have to define some implicit conversions.

Note: the class `Foo` is inside a library so I cannot edit that code. I need to do it outside `Foo`.

I could not find answer to this particular case despite there being several examples of using `Numeric` types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full signature for `List`'s `sum` method is:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B
```

So you must provide an implicit `Numeric` for your class, or some superclass of your class:

```
implicit val fooNumeric = new Numeric[Foo] {
  def compare(x: Foo, y: Foo): Int = ???
  def plus(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = ???
  ... other methods ...
}
```

My guess is `sum` only needs `plus` to work correctly, but you'll at least have to give a dummy implementation of the other abstract `Numeric` methods to get it to compile.

Answer (score 3):

You can define necessary implicit:

```
  class Foo(val b:BigDecimal) {
    def +(f:Foo) = new Foo(b+f.b)
  }
  object Foo {
    implicit val numericFoo: Numeric[Foo] = new Numeric[Foo] {
      override def plus(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = new Foo(x.b + y.b)
      override def minus(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = new Foo(x.b - y.b)
      override def times(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = new Foo(x.b * y.b)
      override def negate(x: Foo): Foo = new Foo(-x.b)
      override def fromInt(x: Int): Foo = new Foo(x)
      override def toInt(x: Foo): Int = x.b.toInt
      override def toLong(x: Foo): Long = x.b.toLong
      override def toFloat(x: Foo): Float = x.b.toFloat
      override def toDouble(x: Foo): Double = x.b.toDouble
      override def compare(x: Foo, y: Foo): Int = x.b.compare(y.b)
    }
  }
```

or just

```
implicit val numericFoo: Numeric[Foo] = new Numeric[Foo] {
  override def plus(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = x + y
  override def minus(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = ???
  override def times(x: Foo, y: Foo): Foo = ???
  override def negate(x: Foo): Foo = ???
  override def fromInt(x: Int): Foo = new Foo(x)
  override def toInt(x: Foo): Int = ???
  override def toLong(x: Foo): Long = ???
  override def toFloat(x: Foo): Float = ???
  override def toDouble(x: Foo): Double = ???
  override def compare(x: Foo, y: Foo): Int = ???
}
```

Or you can define your own extension method

```
  implicit class FooList(foos: List[Foo]) {
    def sum1: Foo = foos.foldLeft(new Foo(0))(_ + _)
  }

  l.sum1
```